# What was the need to introduce enums in Java 5

Tags: enums, java-5

I am going through Enums that were introduced in Java 1.5. In Effective Java 2'nd Edition it's mentioned that before Java 1.5 there were int and String enum patterns which were having some deficiencies.

I understood the cons of int enum patterns but while going through String enum patterns I got the basic idea but didn't get the deep sense of below statements 
mentioned under Item30 in Effective Java:

> This variant, known as the String enum pattern, is
>   even less desirable. While it does provide printable strings for its constants, it can lead
>   to performance problems because it relies on string comparisons.
>   Worse, it can lead naive users to hard-code string constants into
>   client code instead of using field names. If such a hard-coded string
>   constant contains a typographical error, it will escape detection at
>   compile time and result in bugs at runtime.

Can anyone help me in understanding what these lines explaining. I would appreciate if it can be explained with some code snippet.

Thanks

Comment: Which part are you asking about? There's a fair amount there. "If such a hard-coded string constant contains a typographical error, it will escape detection at compile time and result in bugs at runtime." is pretty clear.

Comment: A `String` variable/expression can accept *any* String value. It is not a closed-set. Enumerations provide a compile-time verifiable closed-set: `EnumX` value 'must' be one of `{ A, B, as_defined_in_the_particular_enum_set.. }`.

Comment: Arguably a similar 'need' as Generics: it allows a *stronger* type system that can increase verification of possibly-valid code (ie. it can reject more programs that are *not* type-valid) at compilation; and ensure that the 'less safe' places are dealt with explicitly.

Comment: @user2864740 but typographical error can also be done while defining enum values. Right ?

Comment: @Manish The goal of a stronger type system, including enums, is to *eliminate* a subset of errors that ***can** be caught/detected* during the compilation phase, which leads to a *reduction* of total/possible errors. Code that is broken is broken and is outside *type correctness* of the program; for broken code, see the Halting Problem, in that "is the program / algorithm broken?" is largely undecidable (ie. not determinable during compilation). There are some tools to aid *program correctness*, but that is a *different* topic not directly related to type safety (and enums).

Comment: @Manish tldr; With strings/int "enums" and pre-Generics, the Java 1.4 type-system had some relatively large 'type-safety holes'; with proper enums (and Generics), the Java compiler can provide increased *type correctness*; program correctness is unrelated to this additional type-safety.